# Parsing a series of lambda calculus terms

Tags: parsing, haskell, lambda-calculus

I am writing a lambda calculus parser in Haskell and I can't find a solution to fix its current problem.

How I parse expressions:

```
expr :: Parser LamExpr
expr = do terms <- some $ token term
          return $ foldl1 LamApp terms
```

How I parse terms:

```
term :: Parser LamExpr
term = do symbol "("
          e     <- expr
          symbol ")"
          return e

   <|> do symbol "\\"
          x     <- var
          symbol "->"
          e     <- expr
          return $ LamAbs x e

   <|> do {x <- var; return $ LamVar x}

   <|> do {name <- macroName; return $ LamMacro name}
```

On input "x1 x2) x3" my parser returns

```
LamApp (LamVar 1) (LamVar 2)
```

Parsing should fail as it is syntactically incorrect, but it still parses the first application. I think this is because of `do terms <- some $ token term` which will parse as much as it can due to `some`.

How can I fix this so that the whole parsing fails instead of one section?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using some parsec variant.  You just have to add an `eof` to the end of your parser.

```
parseInput = do
    e <- expr
    eof
    pure e  -- (*)
```

Or for short using a `Control.Applicative` combinator:

```
parseInput = expr <* eof
```

---

*(*) btw the community is starting to use `pure` instead of `return` these days*

Comment: its actually an assignment so we were given a library of parsing functions to build off of. so I don't have access to `eof`, does it parse the end of a string?

Comment: @ICTOAUN, yes.  Perhaps you can make a parser combinator that does the same thing based on your library -- that succeeds only when (the remainder of) the input is empty.